# Azure application Gateway returns 502 with AKS build from terraform

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

Im currently testing to build aks cluster with application gateway ingress from terraform following this documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/terraform/terraform-create-k8s-cluster-with-aks-applicationgateway-ingress

After successfully creation, i tried to serve a guestbook tutorial through the app gateway ingress controller:

https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/docs/tutorial.html#expose-services-over-http

The application started normally but the application gateway returns HTTP 502 error.

Comment: that guide doesnt make sense to me, they create appgw without tying it to the vms

Comment: Do you check if the backend service and the ingress in the right state?

Comment: I found solution here : github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/27904 The problem was documentation, ingress controller wasnt deployed

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you mean by `was never deployed`?

Comment: Can you provide more examples of what you're doing and stuff? Not just directly from the blog, but what you're typing in and what it looks like when you get yoru errors?